# Apple website animations do not work on Safari 11

Tags: macos, safari

I have a Late 2011 15" MBP with El Capitan(highest update). The animations on Apple website do not work on any browsers (Safari 11, Firefox 57, Chrome) even if the discrete GPU is being utilized. WebGL, CSS animation settings are turned on. The same animation works on other Windows PC with any browser. Is there any setting I can change?

Answer (score 2):

'Block auto-playing videos' related? https://www.cultofmac.com/488858/safari-11/